# лагает NetBeans 8.0.2 под UBUNTU 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

очень тупит NetBeans 8.0.2. (долгое перемещение между вкладками, подгружает когда ввожу доп.код, долго открывает, закрывает папки, долго выбирает нужный вариант, долго импортирует пакеты...)

стоит еще Eclipse - летает без проблем.

Lenovo z-50
Память 4,7 ГиБ
Процессор AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G × 4
ТИП ОС 64-разрядная
UBUNTU 14.04 LTS
выделено для NetBeans - 675,6 MиБ.
диск обычый.

**netBeans about:**

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.0.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.7.0_79; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 24.79-b02
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.7.0_79-b14
System: Linux version 3.16.0-50-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en (nb)

> netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true --locale en"

Подскажите как ускорить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

помогло установить Java 8 версию 
и

```
в netbeans.conf — netbeans_default_options -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m поменять на J-Xss8m -J-Xms128m
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в Java. После того как я обновил в Debian `openjdk-8-jre` до версии `8u66-b01-4` появились те же симптомы. Попробуйте установить последнюю версию с официального сайта - [Загрузить программное обеспечение Java для Linux](https://www.java.com/ru/download/linux_manual.jsp). На данный момент это `jre-8u60`. Далее следует указать путь в `netbeans_jdkhome`.

Comment: java version "1.7.0_79" стоит, я пока не обновлялся

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память то NetBeans 8 не работает с 7-й java. Что у Вас указано для NetBeans в О программе?

Comment: поправил вопрос. посмотрите плиз

Comment: Все таки на java 7-й версии работает. В таком случае у меня нету вариантов. На 8-й версии при аналогичных симптомах (плюс на  c++ проектах послетала значительная часть подсветки и автодополнения кода) мне помог откат на более старую версию java.